# determine IP address for interface configuration

Tags: networking, rhel

I am configuring an eth1 interface on in Red Hat, but I don't understand exactly what the IP address should be.

I'm given an IP of 10.237.128.0/25.
This means that the NETMASK would be 255.255.255.128; I understand this portion.

What I don't understand, is if eth1 is in fact a host device, what would the IPADDR address be?

Here are my guesses:

```
10.237.128.0/25
10.237.128.0 (since the NETMASK variable will be declared, thus making /25 unnecessary)
10.237.128.1-126 (If eth1 is considered a host, 8 0-bits and 8 1-bits would be unavailable on the network as a host, and the 128 bit is the network.)
```

Which one of these is correct and why?

Answer (score 0):

probably it's best to post this on https://serverfault.com/ , anyway a single interface can have multiple IP address, it depends on what you mean by "interface", you can have an IP even without having real hardware, especially on linux ( loopback interfaces ).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the config scripts under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, then the second one would be correct. Netmask is specified separately, as you mentioned.

```
IPADDR="10.237.128.0"
NETMASK="255.255.255.128"
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets look over your guesses and why each is good/bad.  All IP addresses that are displayed with an X means that the number is not known or needed as it is an example.

10.237.128.0/25
good: it is in the domain ( 10.237.x.x ) you were given, subset of domain ( x.x.128.x) so you just need to decide which connection of domain and subset within the 0/25.

10.237.128.0 (since the NETMASK variable will be declared, thus making /25 unnecessary)
Posibly good:  If you start looking in to ROUTERS you will see alot choose an ip ( example of x.x.x.1 or x.x.x.10 ) and the 0/25 is a range, not an actual number.

10.237.128.1-126 (If eth1 is considered a host, 8 0-bits and 8 1-bits would be unavailable on the network as a host, and the 128 bit is the network.)

BAD: Host addresses are usually the low end and also 1-126 will potentialy move it to a range that security software will call invalid for HOST connections.  IP addresses can be ( technicaly, not in real world working conditions ) 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 with a few reserved ( like 127.0.0.1 for LocalHost connection IN the device ) making any connection above x.x.x.120 possibly not an actual host but a ' spoofed ' host that is trying to force itself as a host connetion in order to monitor and possibly intercept the network traffic.

For more reading, try the wiki at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address